# What syntax is this: std::thread t([&] () { ... });?

Tags: c++

I was reading through the source code from Facebook's Proxygen, and I noticed some syntax I'd never seen before:

```
std::thread t([&] () {
    server.start();
});
```

Source: https://github.com/facebook/proxygen/blob/master/proxygen/httpserver/samples/push/PushServer.cpp

Is it an anonymous method? And what is the value of `&`, is it the thread?

It looks confusing because if it is an anonymous method how is `server` accessible, isn't it out of scope?

Comment: It's a lambda. The `[&]` means that variables in the current scope are captured by reference (in this case `server`).

Comment: Its a *lambda function*.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Comment: Thanks guys. Care to answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this code uses anonymous function. The basic syntax is : `[capture-list] (list-params) { function-body}`. So what [&] does is

> captures all automatic variables odr-used in the body of the lambda by reference

You can read more [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)